# UPDATE slow when setting column to NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with 80,000 rows and am executing the following query:

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET HelloWorldID = NULL
WHERE HelloWorldID = @helloWorldID
```

`HelloWorldID` is an `int` and the `@helloWorldID` parameter is also `int`.

The query is taking too long and I'd like to optimize it. I created a nonclustered index on `HelloWorldID` but it didn't matter. I may have to redesign this...maybe put the `HelloWorldID` on another table that links it to the `TableName` table?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan somewhere? What is the data type of the parameter, what is the data type of the column, and how many rows do you expect to match? While it is running, what do you see for wait types and blocking for that SPID in `sys.dm_exec_requests`?

Comment: The data type of both are 'int'. I expect to match one row. Where can I post execution plan and in what format? I see PAGEIOLATCH_EX for wait type and no blocking but the command is DELETE.

Comment: If the command is delete, then perhaps (a) this is part of a larger query / transaction, or (b) there is a trigger that you don't know about or haven't investigated.

Comment: Execution plan in .sqlplan format. If you have the free [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/) you can post .queryanalysis files to [answers.sqlperformance.com](http://answers.sqlperformance.com/) from within the tool. Otherwise just pick your favorite file sharing service, as long as it doesn't require us to create an account or log in. *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I posted on your site with a link to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the command you're waiting on is `DELETE` I have to guess that there is a trigger on `dbo.TableName` and that it is performing additional work that you do not expect. Or perhaps some `CASCADE` option that is affecting other tables that have triggers on them.

Comment: I don't have any triggers on that database.

Comment: @richinator38 well, SQL Server won't magically turn your `UPDATE` into a `DELETE` on its own, so there must be something going on that you haven't found yet (or haven't disclosed). Why are you using `ROWLOCK`? Is this part of a larger transaction?

Comment: It looks like something else is going on here.  The code I posted is in a sproc that runs quickly if I do it for one call at a time.  However, the sproc is being called from an SSIS job that is looping through multiple ids.  If I look at the Profiler output, the "Audit Logout" event takes the most time it seems.

Comment: I would suggest using table-valued parameters for this instead of SSIS calling the procedure over and over again for a bunch of values. Where does SSIS get the list of IDs to call the procedure for?

Comment: Another procedure gets the list of IDs. I'm using the ID to 1) delete the document from the source DB and then 2) update the row to null out the ID of the document. I'm playing around with transaction options in SSIS and that seems to help a little.

Comment: Option 2) mentioned previously should state "in the destination DB"

Comment: It turns out the problem was in the other sproc I was calling against a different database which did have triggers on DELETE. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much rows will be updated by this query.
If you're updating a lot of rows, say 30% of the table, then the index will actually slow down the query (as index will be updated along with the table, and it won't help with filtering the rows for update). Also ROWLOCK will slow it down, because the engine will issue a separate lock for each row (as opposed to pagelocks that would occur normally).
Try removing the index and running this update using `WITH(TABLOCK)` just to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...didn't seem to make any difference as I'm only expecting 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem sometimes.  Your query is dependent upon simultaneously getting a write-lock on every row in the table meeting the conditions of the WHERE-Clause .  Depending on your needs for full 'ACID', you could do something like this:

```
SELECT getdate()  -- force @@rowcount=1
while @@rowcount > 0
UPDATE TOP (1000) dbo.TableName 
SET HelloWorldID = NULL
WHERE HelloWorldID = @helloWorldID
```

This will do the update is smaller chunks, and help overcome locking issues.  But remember, this-method gives up on doing this-query as a single-transaction.  You will need to tune the 1000 to a value that is right for your server.

Comment: The update will update 1000 rows at a time until all the changes are made.The first line 'select getdate()' forces @@rowcount=1.Then the update statements after that put @@rowcount=1000 until there is less than 1000 to update.Then @@rowcount equals the number updated.I do this kind of while loop all the time.

Comment: Yes, I understand what *YOUR* code is trying to do. I'm telling you that the OP's where clause only identifies a single row - so the speed problem has absolutely nothing to do with batching. Your loop will only run one time and still only update one row.

Comment: The OP never said that the field in the where clause was the primary key.He created a nonclusterred index on the field, and is having pagelatch issues, I am presuming it is NOT the PrimaryKey.My solution only helps if it is not the Primary key, and the field is not only not unique in the table, but the value edited is on MANY rows.